# Azure ACR Tasks API? Have an application running in docker container that needs to to build and push images to ACR

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dockerfile

Application was using docker CLI to build and then push an image to azure container registry. Used to work fine on Kubernetes using a python module and docker.sock. But since cluster upgraded docker daemon is gone. Guessing the K8 backend no longer uses docker or has it installled. Also, since docker is going away in kubernetes (i think it said 1.24 I want to get away from counting on docker for the build.

So the application when working was python application running in a docker container. It would take the dockerfile and build it and push it to azure container registry. There are files that get pushed into the image via the dockerfile and they all exist in the same directory as the dockerfile.

Anyone know of different methods to achieve this?

I've been looking at Azure ACR Tasks but I'm not really sure how all the files get copied over to a task and have not been able to find any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that running an Azure ACR Task (Multi-Task or Quick Task) will copy the files over when the command is executed. We're using [Azure ACR Quick Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-overview#task-scenarios) to achieve something similar. If you're just trying to do the equivalent of `docker build` and `docker push`, Quick Tasks should work fine for you too.

For simplicity I'm gonna list the example for a Quick Task because that's what I've used mostly. Try the following steps from your local machine to see how it works. Same steps should also work from any other environment provided the machine is authenticated properly.

First make sure you are in the Dockerfile directory and then:

1. Authenticate to the Azure CLI using `az login`
2. Authenticate to your ACR using `az acr login --name myacr`.
3. Replace the values accordingly and run `az acr build --registry myacr -g myacr_rg --image myacr.azurecr.io/myimage:v1.0 .`
4. Your terminal should already show all of the steps that the Dockerfile is executing. Alternatively you can head over to your ACR and look under `services>tasks>runs`. You should see every line of the Docker build task appear there.

Note: If you're running this task in an automated fashion and also require access to internal/private resources during the image build, you should consider creating a [Dedicated Agent Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/tasks-agent-pools) and deploying it in your VNET/SNET, instead of using the shared/public Agent Pools.

In my case, I'm using terraform to run the `az acr build` command and you can see the Dockerfile executes the `COPY` commands without any issues.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if ACR quick task has a restful API something like az acr build? I looked at PUT method for creating a task. The part that threw new off is how to get the Dockerfile and files into it (and I had errors when trying to play around). I'm tempted to try to run azure CLI commands in the container but since we have just been using REST I was going to try to stick with that.

Comment: Ok for our case we're using az cli commands in containers, and leveraging either a system-assigned identity or a user assigned identity for authentication. Makes things very easy and clean. I would have thought REST API in this case would be an overkill because the az acr commands are quite extensive in what they provide, but again I'm not going to question - you could have a unique scenario where it's more appropriate. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/tasks/create#dockerbuildstep - did you also check the build step, with the dockerfile path and context path?

Comment: Got azure CLI installed in docker image and connected as service principle to run command. It failed with network security enabled so I disabled and it worked. To get it working with network security enabled I had to create an acr agent on the same virtual network and then everything worked as expected when I added the argument to the build for the custom agent I created. Thanks!